# How to use this Custom Ionic Cordova plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, native

I need to use this plugin: https://github.com/jaeyun0/cordova-plugin-m3scan
so i added it to project and initialized in my app.component.ts but next i need use methods from this plugin to handle barcode and i dont know how to do it. I read many articles about this topic, but i don`t found answer.

m3scan.js:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

exports.echo = function () {
    exec(function () {
        console.log("Initialized the M3 SCANNER");
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log("Failed to initialize the M3 SCANNER " + reason);
    }, 'm3scan', 'echo', []);
};
```

m3scan.java ( methods )

```
    @Override

    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), action.toString());
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
        Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        if(action.equals("scanStart")) {
            mBarcode.scanStart();
            scanCallbackContext = callbackContext;
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("scanDispose")) {
            mBarcode.scanDispose();
            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("setPrefix")) {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_SETTING_CHANGE);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "prefix");
            intent.putExtra("prefix_value", args.getString(0));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_SETTING_CHANGE);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "postfix");
            intent.putExtra("postfix_value", args.getString(1));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("setEndCharacter")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_SETTING_CHANGE);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "end_char");

            if(args.getString(0).equals("enter"))
                intent.putExtra("end_char_value", 0);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("space"))
                intent.putExtra("end_char_value", 1);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("tab"))
                intent.putExtra("end_char_value", 2);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("key_enter"))
                intent.putExtra("end_char_value", 3);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("key_space"))
                intent.putExtra("end_char_value", 4);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("key_tab"))
                intent.putExtra("end_char_value", 5);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("none"))
                intent.putExtra("end_char_value", 6);

            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("setSubString")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_SETTING_CHANGE);
            //intent.putExtra("setting", "begin_index");
            intent.putExtra("setting", "begin_index");
            intent.putExtra("begin_value", args.getInt(0));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            intent.putExtra("setting", "end_index");
            intent.putExtra("end_value", args.getInt(1));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("setCode128Length")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 209);
            intent.putExtra("value", args.getInt(0));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 210);
            intent.putExtra("value", args.getInt(1));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("setCode39Length")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 18);
            intent.putExtra("value", args.getInt(0));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 19);
            intent.putExtra("value", args.getInt(1));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("setI2o5Length")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 22);
            intent.putExtra("value", args.getInt(0));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 23);
            intent.putExtra("value", args.getInt(1));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("setOutPutMode")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_SETTING_CHANGE);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "output_mode");

            if(args.getString(0).equals("copy_paste"))
                intent.putExtra("output_mode_value", 0);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("key"))
                intent.putExtra("output_mode_value", 1);
            else if(args.getString(0).equals("output_none"))
                intent.putExtra("output_mode_value", 2);

            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("showToast")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, args.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            callbackContext.success();

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getPrefix")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_GET_SETTING);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "prefix");
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            prefixCallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getSuffix")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_GET_SETTING);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "postfix");
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            postfixCallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getBeginIndex")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_GET_SETTING);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "begin_index");
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            beginIndexCallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getEndIndex")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_GET_SETTING);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "end_index");
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            endIndexCallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getEndChar")) {
            cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_GET_SETTING);
                    intent.putExtra("setting", "end_char");
                    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
                    endCharCallbackContext = callbackContext;
                }
            });
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getCode128Length1")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 209);
            intent.putExtra("value", -1);
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            code128Length1CallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getCode128Length2")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 210);
            intent.putExtra("value", -1);
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            code128Length2CallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getCode39Length1")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 18);
            intent.putExtra("value", -1);
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            code39Length1CallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getCode39Length2")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 19);
            intent.putExtra("value", -1);
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            code39Length2CallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getI2o5Length1")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 22);
            intent.putExtra("value", -1);
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            i2o5Length1CallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getI2o5Length2")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_PARAMETER);
            intent.putExtra("symbology", 23);
            intent.putExtra("value", -1);
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            i2o5Length2CallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("getOutPutMode")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SCANNER_ACTION_GET_SETTING);
            intent.putExtra("setting", "output_mode");
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
            outPutModeCallbackContext = callbackContext;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, final CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        mBarcode = new Barcode(context);
        mManager = new BarcodeManager(context);
        mBarcode.setScanner(true);

        mListener = new BarcodeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBarcode(String s) {
                Log.i("ScannerTest", "result=" + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBarcode(String s, String s1) {
                Log.i("ScannerTest", "result=" + s);
                if(scanCallbackContext != null)
                    scanCallbackContext.success(s);
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:setMessage('data : " + s + "\\ntype : " + s1 + "')");
            }

            @Override
            public void onGetSymbology(int i, int i1) {

            }
        };
        mManager.addListener(mListener);

        // intent filter
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(SCANNER_ACTION_SETTING);
        filter.addAction(SCANNER_ACTION_BARCODE);
        context.registerReceiver(BarcodeIntentBroadcast,filter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        context.unregisterReceiver(BarcodeIntentBroadcast);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver BarcodeIntentBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        private String strPrefix;
        private String strSuffix;
        private int nBegin;
        private int nEnd;
        private int nEndChar;
        private int nOutPutMode;
        private String strBarcode;

        private static final String SCANNER_EXTRA_PREFIX = "m3scanner_prefix";
        private static final String SCANNER_EXTRA_POSTFIX = "m3scanner_postfix";
        private static final String SCANNER_EXTRA_BEGIN_INDEX = "m3scanner_beginindex";
        private static final String SCANNER_EXTRA_END_INDEX = "m3scanner_endindex";
        private static final String SCANNER_EXTRA_END_CHAR = "m3scanner_endchar";
        private static final String SCANNER_EXTRA_OUTPUT_MODE = "m3scanner_output_mode";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("onReceive", intent.getAction());

            if(intent.getAction().equals(SCANNER_ACTION_SETTING)) {
                String extra = intent.getStringExtra("setting");
                if(extra.equals("prefix")) {
                    strPrefix = intent.getExtras().getString(SCANNER_EXTRA_PREFIX);
                    Log.d("onReceive", "strPrefix = " + strPrefix);
                    prefixCallbackContext.success(strPrefix);
                } else if(extra.equals("postfix")) {
                    strSuffix = intent.getExtras().getString(SCANNER_EXTRA_POSTFIX);
                    Log.d("onReceive", "strSuffix = " + strSuffix);
                    postfixCallbackContext.success(strSuffix);
                } else if(extra.equals("begin_index")) {
                    nBegin = intent.getExtras().getInt(SCANNER_EXTRA_BEGIN_INDEX);
                    Log.d("onReceive", "nBegin = " + nBegin);
                    beginIndexCallbackContext.success(nBegin);
                } else if(extra.equals("end_index")) {
                    nEnd = intent.getExtras().getInt(SCANNER_EXTRA_END_INDEX);
                    Log.d("onReceive", "nEnd = " + nEnd);
                    endIndexCallbackContext.success(nEnd);
                } else if(extra.equals("end_char")) {
                    nEndChar = intent.getExtras().getInt(SCANNER_EXTRA_END_CHAR);
                    Log.d("onReceive", "nEndChar = " + nEndChar);
                    endCharCallbackContext.success(nEndChar);
                }else if(extra.equals("output_mode")) {
                    nOutPutMode = intent.getExtras().getInt(SCANNER_EXTRA_OUTPUT_MODE);
                    Log.d("onReceive", "nOutputMode = " + nOutPutMode);
                    outPutModeCallbackContext.success(nOutPutMode);
                }
            } else if(intent.getAction().equals(SCANNER_ACTION_BARCODE)) {
                strBarcode = intent.getExtras().getString(SCANNER_EXTRA_BARCODE_DATA);

                if(strBarcode != null) {

                } else {
                    int nSymbol = intent.getExtras().getInt("symbology", -1);
                    int nValue = intent.getExtras().getInt("value", -1);
                    Log.i("onReceive", "getSymbology [" + nSymbol + "][" + nValue + "]");
                    if(nSymbol != -1) {
                        switch (nSymbol){
                            case 209:
                                code128Length1CallbackContext.success(nValue);
                                break;
                            case 210:
                                code128Length2CallbackContext.success(nValue);
                                break;
                            case 18:
                                code39Length1CallbackContext.success(nValue);
                                break;
                            case 19:
                                code39Length2CallbackContext.success(nValue);
                                break;
                            case 22:
                                i2o5Length1CallbackContext.success(nValue);
                                break;
                            case 23:
                                i2o5Length2CallbackContext.success(nValue);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };


}
```

plugin.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="net.m3mobile.scan" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>m3scan</name>
    <js-module name="m3scan" src="www/m3scan.js">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.m3scan" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="Scan">
                <param name="android-package" value="net.m3mobile.scan.m3scan" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml"></config-file>
        <source-file src="lib/M3SDK.jar" target-dir="app/libs" />
        <source-file src="src/android/m3scan.java" target-dir="src/net/m3mobile/scan" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

app.component.ts

```
declare var m3scan: any;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the methods in this file([here](https://github.com/jaeyun0/cordova-plugin-m3scan/blob/master/www/m3scan.js)) and then you can access within the `m3scan` variable.

For example, as you have `scanStart` method in your java class. you need to register that method in above-mentioned file.

as like:

```
exports.scanStart = function () {
    exec(function () {
        console.log("Initialized the M3 SCANNER");
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log("Failed to initialize the M3 SCANNER " + reason);
    }, 'm3scan', 'scanStart', []);
};
```

after adding this function you need to publish this package and install this in your app.

In you Cordova ionic app, you can expose that method like.

```
m3scan.scanStart().then().catch()
```

Comment: Thanks bro :) But i have another problem with it. When i try to do cordova.exec function with m3scan  from application or from console, its send me error with text " Class not found". When i do cordova.exec with another plugins, they working. I think that could be something with plugin.xml mayby i missed something important with plugin registration or something... Can you help me ?

Comment: @DariuszSzymczak to call the method of plugin, you have to expose it like 
var m3scan = cordova.plugins.m3scan;
m3scan.scanStart().then().catch();

Answer (score 0):

Now its working. I had to do one thing. In exec method for cordova.exec there is parameter that is referrence to plugin.xml  . Before i passed here java class name but that was wrong. Now its working :)
For someone who will search in the future you need to connect name in feature tag with Scan in exec in the www/pluginName.js

```
exports.scan = function (success) {
cordova.exec(success , function(err){
    console.log("M3 BAD: "+err);
    localStorage.setItem('m3','');
},  'Scan', 'scanStart',[]);
```

};